# apache cache-control without validation

Tags: apache

how can I make my browser cache an asset such as an image with a command to tell the browser not to check for updated files? I have static assets that won't ever change and it's a waste to keep asking the server for updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My host doesn't declare favicon.ico files as image/x-icon, so I need the following

```
AddType image/x-icon .ico
```

You set expires as follows, one per type.  Here is an example set (you can use day, week, month, etc. :

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css        "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif       "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/png       "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon    "access plus 1 week"
```

You might also wish to set the Cache header

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$">
   Header add "Cache-Control" "public, max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>
```

Extend as required for other types.  604800 = 1 week in seconds.  Do the math if you want to change this.

## How the browser uses these headers

[RFC 2616 (HTTP/1.1)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13) lays down a framework advice of when and how browsers use this information.  To get an insight into how this works in practice use the Google Chrome developer view (Ctl+Shft+I) Network tab.  (Most other major browsers offer equivalent instrumentation though possibly through an extension pack.)  However this is advisory in that users can elect to ignore this though their browser options and always elect to check the server, or to check the server once per session.  IIRC, some early browsers (e.g. MSIE pre 8) had the check-once-per session as the default option.

Also if you elect to do a page refresh, then most browsers will revalidate all resources on the page using the **If-Modified-Since** and **If-None-Match**, so you need to revisit a link or re-enter the URI to see the normal reuse action.  Likewise most will honour Shift+refresh as a "forced refresh" -- that is no negotiation is carried out.

When I administered the OpenOffice.orf user forums, I once analysed a full month's access logs to see how much caching was being carried out by using a simple algo to determine when reused resources should be cached but where still being fetched by client browsers.  I was surprised to find that this cache-miss rate was over 30% (due to users' browser settings).  However most users access these user forums as a knowledgebase using google to ask about specific problem and then look at a few pages, never to return within the month.  When I restricted myself to the Moderator's IPs (who mostly use Ff or Chrome as their browser) then this rate increased to ~95%.

So clients browsers *do* use this information, but not as much as you might expect.  I also discuss [here](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-58) that browsers also can cache resources when you don't explicitly request this.

Comment: I know how to cache. I'm wanting to tell the server not to even CHECK for a newer version.

Comment: @LordZardeck, IMO your wish is illogical.  mod_expires does an `lstat()` on the file.  Given that this is the file that it is going to read anyway, this is comparable to an lstat of inode already cached in the File system cache.  This costs a few hundred microseconds.  The read itself if not cashed could take a hundred milliseconds or more.  You can't use mod_expires to set an absolute date in the future.  Of course you could just drop the header and have the browser do a cond'l GET.  Work out the overhead on that! ;-?

Comment: Also if you want "the server not to even CHECK" then change your Q.  You said "tell the *browser*..."  BTW, "access plus 1 month" means that the browser will use the locally cached copy for the next month before revalidating.  If you don't like that then put "access + 10 years" or something equally perverse.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did mean browser. I meant to say, "I'm wanting to tell the BROWSER not to even check the SERVER for a newer version". Also, I've tried the expires module, and it still sends a request from the server, receiving a 304 response

Comment: I've updated my response to provide what you where looking for.  If you want a detailed response, then you should think about how you frame the Q :-)

Comment: also try a search on `[apache] cache control votes:3` if you want to see some other good discussion around this subject

Comment: @LordZardeck, is this what you were looking for?